# How to call datepicker by clicking on input Angular

Tags: html, angular, datepicker

This is html file:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

and `datepicker` is calling by clicking to icon (`mat-datepicker-toggle`). ->
[image]

but I want that `datepicker` will be called **by clicking to input without icon** like this
[image]

Here is example angular datepicker -> https://stackblitz.com/angular/xvjleypolka?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.html
If you have another way to integrate datepicker to input in angular welcome

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46344213/angular-material-md-datepicker-open-date-picker-on-input-click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add `(focus)="picker.open()"`

Try like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date"  (focus)="picker.open()">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-undoms?embed=1&file=src/app/datepicker-overview-example.html)**

Comment: I guess i can also add (click)="picker.open()" ?

Comment: Using `(click)="picker.open()"` would actually be better, in my opinion. This way it will open the DatePicker every time you _click_ on the input. Otherwise, if the input field is already focused, the DatePicker will not open on click.

Answer (score 2):

Use like bellow:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" 
  (click)="picker.open()">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gjh17j?file=src/app/datepicker-overview-example.html)

Answer (score 1):

`MatDatePicker` have `open` method to open it manually.

> So just use it on focus of an input `(focus)="picker.open()"`

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (focus)="picker.open()" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```